# Using iTextSharp for HTML to PDF with images on header, footer and body, "Cannot access a closed Stream"

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp and XMLWorker 5.5.12 to convert HTML to PDF, I need to generate a header, a footer and body content.
I was able to generate all with text using a Page Event, the problem comes when I try to insert images in the body and in the Page Event, as soon as I use images in both the `parser.Parse(reader);` line throws error `Cannot access a closed Stream.`.

This is the code I've come so far:

```
protected ActionResult ViewPdf(string viewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData = null,
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = null,
            float marginLeft = 10f, float marginRight = 10f,
            float marginTop = 10f, float marginBottom = 10f,
            IEnumerable<PDFFragmentBaseViewModel> fragments = null)
        {
            if (size == null) size = iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER;
            using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(size, marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom))
            {
                using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outStream);
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    // page event
                    //if (pageEvent != null)
                    //    writer.PageEvent = pageEvent;

                    // css
                    ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
                    //if (cssPath != null)
                    //    cssResolver.AddCssFile(cssPath, true);

                    //Register Image Procesor
                    var tagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
                    tagProcessorFactory.AddProcessor(new ResourceImageHtmlTagProcessor(), new[] { "resimg" });

                    // html 
                    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
                    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);

                    // pipelines
                    PdfWriterPipeline pdfPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
                    HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdfPipeline);
                    CssResolverPipeline cssPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

                    // parse
                    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
                    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(worker);

                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    List<PDFFragmentViewModel> _frags = null;
                    if (fragments != null)
                    {
                        _frags = new List<PDFFragmentViewModel>();
                        foreach (var frag in fragments)
                        {
                            _frags.Add(new PDFFragmentViewModel {
                                Content = REC0Utils.RenderRazorViewToString(frag.ViewName, ControllerContext, new object { }, viewData ?? ViewData),
                                Alignment = frag.Alignment,
                                Leading = frag.Leading,
                                LLX = frag.LLX,
                                LLY = frag.LLY,
                                URX = frag.URX,
                                URY = frag.URY
                            });
                        }
                        //string htmlHeader = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table style=\"width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;\"><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr></table></body></html>";
                        //string htmlHeader = REC0Utils.RenderRazorViewToString(headerViewName, ControllerContext, headerModel, viewData ?? ViewData);
                        writer.PageEvent = new HtmlPageEventHelper(_frags);
                    }
                    document.Open();

                    // Render the view xml to a string, then parse that string into an XML dom.
                    string xmltext = REC0Utils.RenderRazorViewToString(viewName, this.ControllerContext, model, viewData == null ? ViewData : viewData);

                    using (var reader = new StringReader(xmltext))
                    {
                        parser.Parse(reader);
                    }

                    // Close and get the resulted binary data.
                    document.Close();

                    // Send the binary data to the browser.
                    return new BinaryContentResult(outStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
                }
            }

            // Parse the XML into the iTextSharp document.
            //TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmltext);
            //XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, reader);

            //XMLParser textHandler = new XMLParser(doc);
            //textHandler.Parse(xmldoc);
        }
```

And this is the code for the Page Event:

```
public class HtmlPageEventHelper : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        List<PDFFragmentViewModel> _fragments;

        public HtmlPageEventHelper(List<PDFFragmentViewModel> fragments)
        {
            this._fragments = fragments;
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

            var _instance = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();

            // css
            ICSSResolver cssResolver = _instance.GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
            //Register Image Procesor
            var tagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
            tagProcessorFactory.AddProcessor(new ResourceImageHtmlTagProcessor(), new[] { "resimg" });
            // html 
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);
            // pipelines
            PdfWriterPipeline pdfPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdfPipeline);
            CssResolverPipeline cssPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

            // parse
            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(worker);

            foreach (var _frag in _fragments)
            {
                ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);

                //using (var reader = new StringReader(_frag.Content))
                //{
                //    parser.Parse(reader);
                //}

                _instance.ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader(_frag.Content));
                //ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Top, document.Right, document.GetTop(-20), 10, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                ct.SetSimpleColumn(
                    _frag.LLX.HasValue ? document.GetLeft(_frag.LLX.Value) : document.Left,
                    _frag.LLY.HasValue ? document.GetTop(_frag.LLY.Value) : document.Top,
                    _frag.URX.HasValue ? document.GetRight(_frag.URX.Value) : document.Right,
                    _frag.URY.HasValue ? document.GetBottom(_frag.URY.Value) : document.Bottom,
                    _frag.Leading, _frag.Alignment);
                ct.Go();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been investigating and I saw somewhere a suggestion to remove the `using` statements, when I remove them I get a different error:

```
Can not find own context
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

**UPDATE:**
As requested by a comment this is the Stack Trace of the `Can not find own context` error.

```
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker.EndElement(String tag, String ns)
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.EndElement()
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.Process(Char character)
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.ParseWithReader(TextReader reader)
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.Parse(TextReader reader)
   at MvcREC0.WebUI.Controllers.BaseController.ViewPdf(String viewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Rectangle size, Single marginLeft, Single marginRight, Single marginTop, Single marginBottom, IEnumerable`1 fragments) in C:\Pr0g\MVCRec0\WebUI\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 225
   at MvcREC0.WebUI.Controllers.Crudere`6.<Index>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Pr0g\MVCRec0\WebUI\Controllers\Cruder.cs:line 688
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

And this is the Stack Trace for the Inner Exception:

```
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.AbstractPipeline.GetLocalContext(IWorkerContext context)
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.Close(IWorkerContext context, Tag t, ProcessObject po)
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker.EndElement(String tag, String ns)
```

Comment: *"the using statements, when I remove them I get a different error"* - Please also share the stack trace of that error.

Comment: @mkl there you go.

Comment: that looks a bit like iText has issues processing a closing element. Can you post the html in question?

Comment: @mkl I could, but I'm trying with the simplest HTML posible, header and footer are just an img tab each and the body of the document is just a simple table with an image. Besides, the problem doesn't show up when rendering just the body or just the header and the footer, it happens only when images get included in both.
So, do you think the OnPageEnd event is correct? Is that the way to parse images inside the event? I'm not sure if that is the correct way and  I'm almost sure the problem lays there.

Comment: Indeed, I could reproduce the issue. I have no idea for a fix or work around yet, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, what you try to do is not supported by the `XMLWorker` architecture. (I'm actually a bit surprised about this; I think I even in some earlier comment here or there claimed it should work.)

#### In short

The `XMLWorker` architecture does not allow overlapping usages from the same thread. It does allow overlapping usages from different threads and non-overlapping usages in any threading situation, though.

As your headers and footers appear not to depend on the actual page contents, I'd recommend you switch to a two-pass process: In the first pass create the document body using a `Document` and a `PdfWriter` as above, merely without the event listener; in the second pass stamp the headers and footers onto it using a `PdfReader` and a `PdfStamper`. Alternatively you can try the work-around posted at the end of this answer.

#### In detail

The `XMLWorker` keeps a `context` for the current parsing operation in a `Thread` Data Slot (in Java in a `ThreadLocal`).

The contents of the `context` in the current thread are initialized at the start of `XMLParser.ParseWithReader`, and the whole `context` of the current thread is dropped at its end.

The method `XMLParser.ParseWithReader` eventually is used by each `XMLParser.Parse` overload and also by each `XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml` overload.

As soon as two parsing attempts using the `XMLWorker` architecture - e.g. parsing attempts in a page event listener and a parsing attempt filling the body (unless the latter is clearly limited to a single page) - overlap, therefore, they get into each other's way and the attempt finishing first removes the context also used by the other.

#### A work-around

There is a work-around for this issue, at least for situations like the one at hand, if one is ok with using reflection and one's runtime environment allows that:

Whenever one switches to another attempt, one can store the current `context` value and replace it with a value appropriate for the parsing coming up. As `context` is declared `private`, this requires reflection.

In the case at hand that would be:

```
public class HtmlPageEventHelper : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    List<PDFFragmentViewModel> _fragments;
    FieldInfo context;

    public HtmlPageEventHelper(List<PDFFragmentViewModel> fragments)
    {
        this._fragments = fragments;
        context = typeof(XMLWorker).GetField("context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
    {
        [...]
        // parse
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(worker);

        LocalDataStoreSlot contextSlot = (LocalDataStoreSlot) context.GetValue(worker);
        object contextData = Thread.GetData(contextSlot);
        Thread.SetData(contextSlot, null);

        try
        {
            foreach (var _frag in _fragments)
            {
                ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
    
                //using (var reader = new StringReader(_frag.Content))
                //{
                //    parser.Parse(reader);
                //}
    
                _instance.ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader(_frag.Content));
                //ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Top, document.Right, document.GetTop(-20), 10, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                ct.SetSimpleColumn(
                    _frag.LLX.HasValue ? document.GetLeft(_frag.LLX.Value) : document.Left,
                    _frag.LLY.HasValue ? document.GetTop(_frag.LLY.Value) : document.Top,
                    _frag.URX.HasValue ? document.GetRight(_frag.URX.Value) : document.Right,
                    _frag.URY.HasValue ? document.GetBottom(_frag.URY.Value) : document.Bottom,
                    _frag.Leading, _frag.Alignment);
                ct.Go();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.SetData(contextSlot, contextData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very helpful answer.
I'll try your suggestions right away, post back and mark as accepted answer after my test.

Comment: I tried the work-around and it works flawlessly, again thank you very much for helping on this one. I really appreciate it.